# Convert JSON response to gridview

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, gridview

I have the following JSON response from an API which I need to show in a Gridview:

```json
[
    {
        "count": 271,
        "headings": [
            "Application",
            "Host",
            "os_type",
            "os_version",
            "model",
            "vendor",
            "virtual"
        ],
        "kind": "BSI",
        "next": "NextROW",
        "next_offset": 100,
        "offset": 0,
        "results": [
            [
                "Customer Documents Archive System",
                "Microsoft Network LoadBalancer mainserver running on 10.75.0.99",
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
            ],
            [
                "Customer Documents Archive System Group",
                "Microsoft Network LoadBalancer server1 running on 10.128.2.143",
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
            ],
            [
                "Customer Documents Archive System Group",
                "Microsoft Network LoadBalancer server2 running on 10.21.5.100",
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
            ],       
            [
                "KIOSK",
                "EastServer",
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
            ],
            [
                "Hotline",
                "EastServer",
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
            ],
            [
                "ProjectWise",
                "NorthServer",
                "Windows",
                "Server 2012 R2",
                "VMware Virtual Platform",
                "VMware, Inc.",
                true
            ],
            [
                "SMS System",
                "CentralServer",
                "Windows",
                "Server 2016",
                "VMware Virtual Platform",
                "VMware, Inc.",
                true
            ]
],
        "results_id": "QnVzaW5lc3N"
    }
]
```

I am using the following code:

```
 Dim steamreader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(stream)
 Dim strdata As String = steamreader.ReadToEnd
 Dim rs As List(Of Root) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Root))(strdata)

 GridView1.DataSource = rs
 GridView1.DataBind()


Public Class Root
        Public Property count As Integer
        Public Property headings As List(Of String)
        Public Property kind As String
        Public Property [next] As String
        Public Property next_offset As Integer
        Public Property offset As Integer
        Public Property results As List(Of List(Of Object))
        Public Property results_id As String
    End Class
```

GridView HTML:

```html
 <asp:GridView ID = "GridView1" runat = "server">
```

Required Output from JSON data:

[image: Example of desired output]

The above code is not working. Can anyone can guide me in how I can show data from the JSON in a gridview using "headings" in the JSON response as Gridview columns headers and corresponding data in "results" as row data for the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way your data is arranged, you need to extract the data for each set of results into a DataTable, and add those datatables to a DataSet.

I used Windows Forms, but you should be able to adapt it to use an ASP.NET GridView with little trouble:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class Form1

    Public Class Root
        Public Property count As Integer
        Public Property headings As List(Of String)
        Public Property kind As String
        Public Property [next] As String
        Public Property next_offset As Integer
        Public Property offset As Integer
        Public Property results As List(Of List(Of Object))
        Public Property results_id As String
    End Class

    Sub ShowData(f As String)
        Dim allResults As List(Of Root)
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(f)
            Dim dataAsJson As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
            allResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Root))(dataAsJson)
        End Using

        Dim ds As New DataSet()

        For Each resultSet In allResults
            Dim dt As New DataTable(resultSet.results_id)

            For Each heading In resultSet.headings
                dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = heading, .DataType = Type.GetType("System.String")})
            Next

            For i = 0 To resultSet.results.Count - 1

                Dim nr = dt.NewRow()

                For j = 0 To resultSet.results(i).Count - 1
                    Dim thisItem = resultSet.results(i).Item(j)
                    nr(j) = If(thisItem Is Nothing, "-", CStr(thisItem))
                Next

                dt.Rows.Add(nr)

            Next

            ds.Tables.Add(dt)

        Next

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim j = "C:\temp\SO68055446.json"
        ShowData(j)

    End Sub

End Class
```

[image: Results items from JSON]

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work. I would double check what strData (do a debug.print(strData) check in your debug (or output window depending on your settings).

I just dropped in a text box, grid view. With this:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="125px"
            TextMode="MultiLine" Width="285px"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Width="111px" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div style="width:40%">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover"></asp:GridView>
        </div>
```

I then just cut + pasted your json into the text box

And I get this result:

[image]

So, this should work. I created the class as a separate module (class), and then pasted in your class for the data.

I can only guess that the json you posted is NOT what you have from that stream reader.

My code above for the button was this:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim strJSON As String = TextBox1.Text

    Dim rs As List(Of RootTest)

    rs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of RootTest))(strJSON)

    GridView1.DataSource = rs
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

and the class was:

```
Public Class RootTest
    Public Property count As Integer
    Public Property headings As List(Of String)
    Public Property kind As String
    Public Property [next] As String
    Public Property next_offset As Integer
    Public Property offset As Integer
    Public Property results As List(Of List(Of Object))
    Public Property results_id As String
End Class
```

Comment: The output you showed in the gridview is what i am also getting right now. I mentioned in my question that i need "headings" property in JSON as gridview columns headers and "results" property in JSON as my rows against those columns.